# Error when trying to ban url with Varnish Cache

Tags: cache, varnish, class

I've updated the [EcomDev_Varnish](https://github.com/EcomDev/EcomDev_Varnish) module to it's latest version and it seems I've gotten everything properly running, but as a test I tried following command: `php ecomdev-varnish.php cache:ban -v b2b_int/customer/account/login/` from the */var/www/src/shell* directory and it give the following error:

```
PHP Fatal error:  Class 'ride\library\varnish\VarnishPool' not found in /var/www/src/app/code/community/EcomDev/Varnish/Model/Connector.php on line 76
PHP Stack trace:
PHP   1. {main}() /var/www/src/shell/ecomdev-varnish.php:0
PHP   2. EcomDev_Varnish_Shell->run() /var/www/src/shell/ecomdev-varnish.php:238
PHP   3. EcomDev_Varnish_Shell->runCacheBan() /var/www/src/shell/ecomdev-varnish.php:136
PHP   4. EcomDev_Varnish_Model_Connector->getVarnishPool() /var/www/src/shell/ecomdev-varnish.php:208
PHP   5. EcomDev_Varnish_Model_Connector->_initVarnishPool() /var/www/src/app/code/community/EcomDev/Varnish/Model/Connector.php:62
```

The file in question is: */src/app/code/community/EcomDev/Varnish/Model/*[Connector.php](https://github.com/EcomDev/EcomDev_Varnish/blob/master/src/app/code/community/EcomDev/Varnish/Model/Connector.php) (I have not edited any of the files).

The line in question is:
`$this->pool = new VarnishPool();` (protected function _initVarnishPool).

I've tried to edit this line to `... = new ride\library\varnish\VarnishPool();`, as I've found in answers to similar questions, also no succes (I've done this without the `()` at the end, but no difference).

Has anyone come across this before or knows how to fix this? Maybe I've done something wrong during installation/update, but this, however possible, seems unlikely since everything else appears to work.

Many thanks

Answer (score 0):

I've figured out the problem, apparently I did goof up during installation. I installed the vendor in the wrong directory, so the autoload couldn't be reached and it couldn't handle the namespaces properly.